# A#sus4 or A#add11 Chord?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

Recently I bought a 6 string bass and I've been going through Steve Bailey's work. I was disecting A Chick From Corea and now I'm quite stumpted. There is a common phrasing that continuously happens in the song, it's this chord that I cant figure out. It's either a sus4 or add11 chord. The song is in C minor (I'm pretty sure). Here's an example of the chord being used: Cm7-A#(sus4 or add 11)- A#m7- G#(sus4 or add 11). It's used as a stepping stone it seems, kinda like a sus chord. I dont believe the major add 11 chords would be suitable with any modal interchange approaches for I've looked at a few already. The notes of the (A#) chord are A#-A-Eb and the it's the same pattern for the other unknown chords. It seems like a sus4 chord but it has a major 7th which is really throwing me off. I thought sus chords had dominant 7ths. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Sus chords substitute the 4th or 2nd for the 3rd, which is absent. No sus chords have a dom 7th as a rule. Obviously that can be added, but by then, it's more than a mere sus chord . Add 11 is exactly what it says - the 4th (11th) is in addition* to the basic triad.  A# is far better known as Bb. Try not to mix # and b - it confuses. -1 for a confusing/confused question.

Comment: So it's a Bbmaj7sus4 chord? No need to be rude, I'm quite young, just trying to wrap my head around something new.

Comment: No rude intentions! If you feel it's so, flag it for the attention of the moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a very specific voicing.  And there are only 3 notes, not really enough to firmly define any chord beyond a triad (and this is certainly not a triad!)  Considering the next chord is Bbm7, I'm inclined to label it Bbmaj7(sus4).    But it's not a very useful label.  With just that information, a musician won't play what's needed.   So use notation.  Chord symbols don't cut it here.